# How to configure adfs for sharepoint online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, adfs

we have user credentials in an on-premise ADFS.we have adfs installed on a machine,how to establish trust between sharepoint online and adfs?How do we get adfs url that authenticates user credentials and generates security token?

Comment: Show me some code, something you have already done but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to Set up a trust between AD FS and Azure AD. Run the powershell:

```
Connect-MsolService
Set-MsolAdfscontext -Computer <AD FS primary server>
Convert-MsolDomainToFederated –DomainName <domain>
```

Below article would be helpful to you:

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/ITOps-Talk-Blog/Step-By-Step-Setting-up-AD-FS-and-Enabling-Single-Sign-On-to/ba-p/295302

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/videos/configuring-ad-fs-for-user-sign-in-with-azure-ad-connect/

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sambetts/2014/09/09/setup-sharepoint-online-on-premises-single-sign-on-sso/